# TooMuchSpace error when running uplc profiling tool on simple minting policy

Tags: plutus, cbor, mintingpolicy

I have the following minting policy:

```
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -fplugin-opt PlutusTx.Plugin:profile-all #-}

{-# INLINABLE verify_mint #-}
verify_mint :: () -> V2.ScriptContext  -> Bool
verify_mint () _ = (3::Integer) == 2+1

policy :: V2.MintingPolicy
policy = V2.mkMintingPolicyScript 
    $$(PlutusTx.compile [|| Typed.mkUntypedMintingPolicy verify_mint ||])
```

which I compiled into the cbor file with

```
writeMintingPolicy :: "test.plutus" policy

writeMintingPolicy :: Haskell.FilePath -> V2.MintingPolicy -> IO (Haskell.Either (FileError ()) ())
writeMintingPolicy file 
    = writeFileTextEnvelope @(PlutusScript PlutusScriptV2) file Haskell.Nothing 
    . PlutusScriptSerialised 
    . SBS.toShort 
    . LBS.toStrict 
    . serialise 
    . V2.getMintingPolicy
```

However, when I tried to use `uplc` to profile it I obtained the following error:

```
uplc evaluate -i test.plutus --if flat --trace-mode LogsWithBudgets -o logs

uplc: Flat deserialisation failure: TooMuchSpace (0x00000042005e893d,S {currPtr = 0x00000042005e6015, usedBits = 3})
CallStack (from HasCallStack):
  error, called at executables/src/PlutusCore/Executable/AstIO.hs:145:17 in plutus-core-1.5.0.0-inplace-plutus-core-execlib:PlutusCore.Executable.AstIO
```

Can anyone help?